# submit button in HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that is like the following,

```
<button type = "submit">submit</button>
```

how do I get JS to read the that it has been pressed without changing the HTML code?

Also I have a button that is

```
<button class="add">add</button>
```

How do I get JS to read the click without changing the code?

Comment: without changing the HTML code MEANS??

Answer (score 2):

You would select the element using whichever one of the several DOM element selection functions (`.querySelector()`, `.getElementsByTagName()`, `.getElementsByClassName()`, etc.) takes your fancy, attach an event listener for the click event, and then in the listener do whatever you want.

```js
// document.querySelector('button.add') to select by class, or...
document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  alert('The button was clicked.')
})
```

```html
<button type = "submit">submit</button>
```

Note that if you had more than one button on the page then you would need to use `.querySelectorAll()` (or one of the other functions I mentioned) to return a list, then loop over the list to attach event handlers to each one. Or attach a handler to their common containing element. If you want to do something *different* for each then you need some way to distinguish between them, e.g., if they're in different containers or something.

Answer (score 0):

```
var buttons=document.getElementsByTagName("button");////returns an array of all buttons 
//assuming that you have only one button with type == submit otherwise loop here
if(buttons[0].getAttribute("type")=="submit")
{
buttons[0].addEventListener("click",function(){
    //you code goes here
});
}


var buttons=document.getElementsByClassName("add");//returns an array of buttons with class as add
//assuming that you have only one button with class add
buttons[0].addEventListener("click",function(){
    //you code goes here
});
```